# Angular 2: Attribute Directive not receiving Input Values

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have made a heatMap Attribute directive which is not receiving the values when passed while calling.

HeatMap Directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[HeatMap]',
})

export class HeatMapDirective{

    @Input('startVal') public startVal: string;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        this.processHeatMap();
    }

    processHeatMap() {
     console.log(this.startVal); // prints undefined.
    }
}
```

HTML Element:

```
    <td class="pad-10" [startVal]="'25'" HeatMap> 25 </td>
```

I have a scenario where i need to pass both string and numeric values but both are not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: No Errors! `console.log(this.startVal); // prints undefined.`

Comment: Check angular2 lifecycle hooks. There are no initialized @Input values in constructor

Answer (score 0):

Change your html as:

```
<td class="pad-10" [startVal]="'25'" HeatMap> 25 </td>
```

Comment: I missed it while adding it here, its present in the actual implementation

Comment: Check value inside 'ngOnInit' function like : ngOnInit() { console.log(this.startVal); }

Answer (score 0):

Input values are not initialized yet when addressing them from the constructor, address them from ngOnInit() like that :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.processHeatMap();
}
```